# jQuery DataTables plugin: adding a checkbox dynamically

Tags: jquery, datatables

When adding a row dynamically using [jQuery DataTables plugin](http://www.datatables.net/), what do I do if one of the cells has to be, say, a checkbox? Just put the HTML in quotes?

Comment: Are you talking about datatables.net?

Comment: @chobo, no, not .net. The jquery plugin called DataTables. @Sar I haven't tried anything yet. Feel free to ignore me while I try that.

Comment: Can you put a link. There seems to be many things called DataTables.

Comment: @cho -- I see, I competely misread your comment. Yes, it's the thing from datatables.net. However, I've hit a much dumber problem in before I can even try this issue here.

Comment: @cho It was a stupid error not worth discussing here. All is well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok now I know it is the plugin that I am using.

I did mine on the server but you should just write the html in the column.

I will try to make an example in a few minutes.

This is how my checkbox comes from the server

```
"CheckBox":"\u003cinput type=\"checkbox\"\u003e\u003c/input\u003e"
```

However this should work

```
dataTable.fnAddData(['<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" />','SomeOtherDataForAnotherColumn']);
```

Comment: `Deprecated` Custom display function that will be called for the display of each cell in this column.
[check here](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns)