# How to show checkboxes in jquery.datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using Datatables and I have the following code to generate the table. I want to display checkboxes for the read, write, execute and admin values.
If the value is equal to 1 , I want the checkbox to be checked. and if 0 checkboxes unchecked.

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
                     "sScrollY": "500px",                                
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": "sources/sample.json"
                } );


            } );
        </script>
```

HTML

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="20%">Browser</th>
                            <th width="25%">Read</th>
                            <th width="25%">Write</th>
                            <th width="15%">Execute</th>
                            <th width="15%">Admin</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
                    </table>
```

JSON

```
{ "aaData": [
    ["Trident","0","0","0","1"],
    ["Trident","0","1","0","0"],
    ["Trident","0","0","1","1"],
    ["Trident","0","0","1","1"],
    ["Trident","0","0","1","1"],
    ["Trident","0","0","0","0"],
    ["Gecko","1","1","1","1"],
    ["Gecko","0","0","0","1"],
    ["Other browsers","1","0","0","U"]
] }
```

Comment: It think you're looking to add inline controls to the datatable: [datatable inline controls](http://editor.datatables.net/release/DataTables/extras/Editor/examples/inlineControls.html).also [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444339/jquery-datatables-plugin-adding-a-checkbox-dynamically)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was able to get it to work using the datables mrenderer

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
            "aTargets": [0],
            //"mData": "download_link",
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                if (data == "Gecko") {
                    return '<a href="' + data + '">' + data + ' Download Gecko</a>';
                } else {
                    return '<a href="' + data + '">' + data + ' Download</a>';
                }
            }
        }, {
            "aTargets": [1],
            //"mData": "download_link",
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                if (data == "1") {
                    return '<input type=\"checkbox\" checked value="' + data + '">';
                } else {
                    return '<input type=\"checkbox\" value="' + data + '">';
                }
            }
        }, {
            "aTargets": [2],
            //"mData": "download_link",
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                if (data == "1") {
                    return '<input type=\"checkbox\" checked value="' + data + '">';
                } else {
                    return '<input type=\"checkbox\" value="' + data + '">';
                }
            }
        }, {
            "aTargets": [3],
            //"mData": "download_link",
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                if (data == "1") {
                    return '<input type=\"checkbox\" checked value="' + data + '">';
                } else {
                    return '<input type=\"checkbox\" value="' + data + '">';
                }
            }
        }, {
            "aTargets": [4],
            //"mData": "download_link",
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                if (data == "1") {
                    return '<input type=\"checkbox\" checked value="' + data + '">';
                } else {
                    return '<input type=\"checkbox\" value="' + data + '">';
                }
            }
        }],
        "bFilter": false,
        "sScrollY": "500px",
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "sources/sample.json"
    });
});
```

Comment: I was looking for an example on how to display checkboxes from a json, thanks for this solution, I would like to know how to create a save button to save data back to server after the checkboxes update. Thanks.