# jQuery DataTable - Bind a checkbox column dynamically with server data

Tags: jquery, datatables

In jQuery datatable, how to bind a checkbox column dynamically, when binding server data?

My code:

```
oTable = $("#tblPreProcess").dataTable({
            bProcessing: true,
            bLengthChange: false,
            bFilter: true,
            sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("FetchPreprocessOrders", "Admin")',
            aoColumns: [
               { sTitle: "Order No", bSortable: false ,bSearchable: true},
                { sTitle: "Vol.Weight", bSortable: false },
                { sTitle: "Content", bSortable: false, },               
                 { sTitle: "Bag Number", bSortable: false }                               
            ]               

        });
```

In the code given above, how do I add a checkbox column before 'Order No' column.

Comment: bind which checkboxes to what data?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14131236/1059101

Answer (score 2):

you can do this like below code:

```
    oTable = $("#tblPreProcess").dataTable({
            bProcessing: true,
            bLengthChange: false,
            bFilter: true,
            sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("FetchPreprocessOrders", "Admin")',
            aoColumns: [
               { sTitle: "Select", bSortable: false ,
                 mRender: function (data, type, full)
                 {
                    return '<input type="checkbox" class="selector" data-id="'+ data +'">'
                 },
               { sTitle: "Order No", bSortable: false ,bSearchable: true},
               { sTitle: "Vol.Weight", bSortable: false },
               { sTitle: "Content", bSortable: false, },               
                { sTitle: "Bag Number", bSortable: false }                               
            ]               

        });
```